# Display dropdown selected value in all the jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jsp

I have a header.jsp with a dropdown box as "Role".The header.jsp is made as such to be used in all the other JSP by include directive.After login the landing page is a home page.The user needs to select a value from the drop down box and some pages appear on that basis.The issue is that the selected value from the drop down is refreshed when any of the other jsp's from the list is selected.All the static data are properly passed on to the other JSP's.how can be the value persisted throughout.The piece of code(header.jsp) as below

```
<div class='header'>    
    <div class='top_header text-center'>
        <span>Welcome:</span>
        <c:out value="${sessionScope.displayName}" />
        &nbsp;|&nbsp; <span>Role:</span>                        
        <select id="role" class="role_select" name="role" onchange="submitRole(this);">
            <option id="roleOption" value="Select Role">Select Role</option>
        <c:forEach var="role" items="${sessionScope.role}">                     
            <option value='${role}'>                    
                <c:out value="${role}"/>
                <c:set var="SelectRole" scope="session" value="${role}" />                  
            </option>
        </c:forEach>                        
        </select>

        &nbsp;|&nbsp; <span><a href='logout'>Logout</a></span> <span>
            <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                <div>${error}</div>
            </c:if> <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                <div>${message}</div>
            </c:if>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='pull-left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
            <span>Feedback System</span>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
You have to read that value of the selected role and and set it into either the request.setAttribute("SelectRole", "value")
or in session.setAttribute("SelectRole", "value") and in the option tag do the following

<option value="${role}" ${role == SelectRole?'selected="selected"':''}>${role}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks.This worked, but after implementing this the default option value (Select Role) is not selected when landing the page.Code as below `<select id="role" class="role_select" name="role" onchange="submitRole(this);">
     <option id="roleOption"  value="Select Role">Select Role</option> 
   <c:forEach var="role" items="${sessionScope.role}">        
    <option value='${role}' ${role == role?'selected="selected"':''}>              
              ${role}              
    </option>    
   </c:forEach>      
   </select>`

Comment: To add a default value

Comment: <option value="${role}" ${role == SelectRole?'selected="selected"':'default_value'}>${role}</option> 

add default value in the empty space.